# как передать переменную make в команду $(shell ...) в make

Tags: linux, c, unix, makefile

Мне нужно получить результат команды  `$(shell find $$(@D) -type f)` в make скрипте. К сожалению, этот код не работает, как я могу передать директорию таргета в эту команду?

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете передать директорию таргета в команду $(shell) с помощью переменной $@D. Вот как это может выглядеть:

```
SOURCES := $(shell find $(TARGET_DIR) -type f)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(SOURCES)
    # Ваша команда сборки
```

Здесь TARGET_DIR - это переменная, содержащая путь к директории таргета, а TARGET - это имя таргета. Переменная SOURCES будет содержать список всех файлов в директории таргета.

Comment: Это не работает, и ответ похож на чат гптшный